# Prettier freezing VS Code in SvelteKit project

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, sveltekit, prettier

Unless I disable the Prettier extension for my SvelteKit project, VS Code gradually gets slower and slower until it's unusable and saving a small file can take up to 30 seconds. Disabling the extension resolved the issue.

I'm using VS Code 1.77.3, OS: Windows_NT x64.

How can I debug what is going wrong and why it's running so slow, and what could be the cause of the issue?

*.prettierrc:*

```
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte", "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
    "pluginSearchDirs": ["."],
    "overrides": [{ "files": "*.svelte", "options": { "parser": "svelte" } }]
}
```

*.eslitrc:*

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier'],
    plugins: ['svelte3', '@typescript-eslint'],
    ignorePatterns: ['*.cjs'],
    overrides: [{ files: ['*.svelte'], processor: 'svelte3/svelte3' }],
    settings: {
        'svelte3/typescript': () => require('typescript')
    },
    parserOptions: {
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaVersion: 2020
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2017: true,
        node: true
    }
};
```

*.postcss.config.cjs*

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

const config = {
  plugins: [
    //Some plugins, like tailwindcss/nesting, need to run before Tailwind,
    tailwindcss(),
    //But others, like autoprefixer, need to run after,
    autoprefixer
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

*tailwind.config.cjs*

```
const config = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },

    plugins: [require('daisyui')]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**Running extensions (without Prettier)**
[image: Running Extensions 1]
[image: Running Extensions 2]
[image: Running Extensions 3]

**Update 22.05**
I tried reproducing the issue by starting with a "clean" slate, so I downloaded Visual Studio Code - Insiders and installed the newest versions of the extensions, and the issue was reproduced when installing the same plugins.

Comment: I have the very same problem since 2-3 weeks, very annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, the decrease in speed is not caused directly by Prettier. Rather, it is caused by other extensions that are installed in Visual Studio Code and affect the formatting. You should investigate whether any of the active extensions are generating errors.

After some test I personally found that disabling "Tailwind CSS IntelliSense" is helping a lot on my vs-code env.

Comment: There haven't been any notable errors from my extensions. Disabling Prettier completely resolves the issue, and the performance is as expected.  I tried disabling Tailwind CSS IntelliSense and re-enabling Prettier but the same issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Tailwind, ESLint, and Prettier combo is ubiquitous, and is issue VS Code team should really look into, even if not a VS Code issue per se. Seems to be no ownership though :-( Recent report here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183021 ; however, this topic is ongoing one and every time try to wean myself off WebStorm, I get reminded of why I use WebStorm. Get what you pay for I guess, but there's a lot to like about VS code -- just unusable for me, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have **settings sync** extension on vscode, try removing it and then reloading VSCode. I had to wait 5 seconds to 10 seconds for formatting, after removing the extension it went down to 80 ms.

[image]